# Prove $G-S$ is open where, $G$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $S$ is a finite non-empty subset of $G$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $G$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $S$ be a non-empty finite subset of G. Prove that $G-S$ is an open set.

**Method 1:** $S$ is finite and $S-G\subseteq S\Rightarrow S-G$ is finite $\Rightarrow (S-G)'=\emptyset\subseteq S-G$
We have, $S-G=S\cap G^c$ is closed $\Rightarrow (S-G)^c=(S\cap G^c)^c=(G\cap S^c)=G-S$ is open.

**Method 2:** Since $\emptyset\ne S$ is finite, we can write $S=\{a_1<a_2<...<a_n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Let $x\in G-S=G\cap S^c\ne\emptyset$ ($\because S$ is a finite subset).
I arrive at three cases: (1) $x<a_1$ , (2) $a_{m-1}<x<a_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N},1<m\le n$ and (3) $x>a_n$.
For each case, I can easily prove that $\exists\epsilon>0\backepsilon N(x,\epsilon)\subseteq G\cap S^c=G-S$, i.e. $G-S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

> Are the methods correct? Which should be preferred?

**Note:** $A'$ is the derived set of $A$ and $A^c$ is the complement of $A$.

Comment: in the first method, how you know this $\phi\subseteq S-G$?

Comment: @Masacroso an empty set is a subset of every set..

Comment: oh, you used the symbol of the greek letter phi to represent the empty set? I assumed you had defined $(G-S)'=\phi$. The empty set is generally represented by the symbols $\emptyset$ or $\varnothing$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proofs are fine, but why not exploit the fact that you are working in a metric space? In this case, a set $S$ is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points. And since a finite $S$ set can not have any limit points (why?), it has them all and so $S$ is closed, which means $G\setminus S$ is open.